# how make recursive Hanoi towers works with OpenMP parallelism

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to make Hanoi towers works with OpenMP, but i feel that isn't working in such  way that the task's are divided in each thread to make the process faster, this is my first time working with threads...
This is what i've been doing

```cpp
# include <iostream>
# include <chrono>
using namespace std;
int cont_times(0);

void hanoi_parallel(const int cant_disk, const char & first, const char & aux, const char & finish)
{
    //have this counter just to know how many times execute this
    cont_times++;
    if (cant_disk == 1){
        cout << "Move disk " << cant_disk << " from " << first << " to " << finish << endl;  
        return;
    }
    # pragma omp parallel
    {
        # pragma omp single
        {
            hanoi(cant_disk - 1, first, finish, aux);
        }
        cout << "Move disk " << cant_disk << " from " << first << " to " << finish << endl; 
        # pragma omp single
        {
            hanoi(cant_disk-1, aux, first, finish);
        } 
    }
}

int main()
{
    int cant_disc(11);
    auto init_time2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    hanoi_parallel(cant_disc, 'A', 'B', 'C');
    auto finish_time2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << cont_times << endl;

    cout << "Duration time parallel: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(finish_time2 - init_time2 ).count() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Actually i tried using: `# pragma omp critical` instead of `# pragma omp single`, but this make the variable "count_times" has the value of ((2^11)-1)*cant_thread.
I tried to change where i call OMP, but have the same problem with "count_times" example:

```cpp
void hanoi(const int cant_disk, const char & first, const char & aux, const char & finish)
{
    cont_times++;
    if (cant_disk == 1){
        cout << "Move disk " << cant_disk << " from " << first << " to " << finish << endl;  
        return;
    }
    hanoi(cant_disk - 1, first, finish, aux);
    cout << "Move disk " << cant_disk << " from " << first << " to " << finish << endl; 
    hanoi(cant_disk-1, aux, first, finish);

int main()
{
    int cant_disc(11);
    auto init_time2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    # pragma omp parallel
    {
        hanoi_parallel(cant_disc, 'A', 'B', 'C');    
    }
    auto finish_time2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << cont_times << endl;

    cout << "Duration time parallel: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(finish_time2 - init_time2 ).count() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions on what i can do

Comment: Why do you want to parallelize the Towers of Hanoi problem?  It is inherently a serial operation.

Comment: Is just for a assigment, i need to compare execution times on normal hanoi and parallel a make some graphics....not a big deal

Comment: When implementing recursive algorithms with OpenMP, one usually uses the `task` construct with a cut-off to disable parallelism at some level in order to not get swamped by the overhead. See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenMP/Tasks) for inspiration.

Comment: thanks @HristoIliev  was so helpfull :)